# Getting error after installing pwa module in magento 2.3.4

Tags: php, mysql, magento2

I am using magento 2.3.4 and now trying to install pwa using below command

composer require magento/pwa

So I have installed successfully this module in backend now when I am running command of compilation then showing error of Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Uid like below

> Class Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Uid does not exist
> Class Magento\CatalogGraphQlAux\Model\Resolver\CustomAttributes\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate p
> roperly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI comm
> and when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add t
> he generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

I have checked for this class but not found in any version of magento2.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on Magento 2.3.6.